# Apache Maven filters for pom properties

Tags: java, maven

I am attempting to create filters for properties. Really this is just a POC. Background it is for testing upped versions of dependencies without having to update the pom. Not sure if this is the right way to go. I can use the filters tag to interpolate the values in another file in conjunction with setting filtering to true:

Working example depending on the file I have as filter I see a different value output in a simple main method.

```
<filters>
    <filter>src/main/filters/dev-app.properties</filter>
</filters>

<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

What I am looking to do though is overwrite values in the pom.xml itself. So if lets say I have `<dep.hibernate.version>` and in the pom it is at version 5.4.0.final but I want to at build time get the latest 5.4.2.final. Is there a way to use filters to override this value in the pom.xml.

I thought this might be possible based on the comment here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

> For example, we can separate "your.name" from the POM by specifying a filter file my-filter-values.properties containing

**Update for clarity**

The version of my project is under my control with various mechanism and plugins. I can use maven to mangage that with no problem.

What I am attempting to do is get past maven's rigidness of version for external 3rd party versions. So for a project I could have:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- Properties for project -->
    <dep.commons.math3.version>3.2</dep.commons.math3.version>
</properties>
```

That is then used like so

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>${dep.commons.math3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And the goal would be I could have a filter for my pipeline that set that property to say 3.5 for it to test that change and only uses that on specific build profiles.

Comment: Wouldn't a script that performs `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` on the [versions-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) to learn the most recent version of each dependency which then updates the POM accordingly be more benefitial? (or `mvn versions:use-next-releases` in short)

Comment: @RomanVottner I think use-next-releases would be for the internal project. The report generation is helpful but I am looking to slowly update from various version not just going straight to the next version. Also, that report is just a report. I essentially want a build that changes the pom dependency versions so CI can take place by just changing the version not the actual pom.

Comment: As outlined in [the documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/usage.html), most goals of the `versions` plugin will modify the POM; with `mvn versions:revert` you could restore the original POM though again. Instead of just going for the next version you can also specify to use the most recent one via `versions:use-latest-versions` or similar methods as explained [here](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/advancing-dependency-versions.html). A pipeline therefore could update the dependencies, perform the tests and revert the changes done to the POM

Comment: @RomanVottner while I agree this is good for the version of the project I do not see how this works with the versions of dependencies that are specified in user properties. I am talking about 3rd party open source versions not 1st party versions of projects I control. I could be missing something so if you have an example that might help.

Comment: To my understanding this is exactly what [`mvn versions:update-properties`](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/update-properties.html) does. It will update the properties used for managing dependency version based on your local repository or all currently active remote repositories, such as maven-central and similar. I've never used automatic updates so far as most often you don't want the latest version but a more stable and tested one, hence I tend to look at the report and update those I know will hardly do any issues

Comment: @RomanVottner thank you that does update properties like I want but still requires modification to the pom in order to set ranges. Once I can get this legacy project to a certain state that will work fine. However right now with the complexity and age of the project (and some SCM issues) I am trying to do this without modifying the pom. That is why I was looking at filters to do it at build.